# raspberrypi 4 wxpython not workding

Tags: python, wxpython

I use a wxpython script that I have from an online course and this script was written for python 2.7. But with the tool python2 to 3 it is for python3 now. I have installed wxpython with pip and also with pip3. But when I try to run the script I receive an error with GTK warning. I am running the script on a raspberry pi 4.
Does someone know how to solve this problem with wxpython or better I'd prefer this script written for Tkinter. I have been busy for some hours now with updating python to 3.8 and also I have the newest GTK.

```
import wx

try:
    with open("test.txt","r+") as data:
        myData = data.read()

except IOError:

    data = open("test.txt","w")
    myData = " "
    data.close()

def save(event):

    with open("test.txt", "w")as data:
        data.write(textArea.Getvalue())

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, title = "Hello world", size = (400,400))
frame.Show()

helloButton = wx.Button(frame, label = "say hello", pos = (160,20),size = (80,20))

app.MainLoop()
```

Update:
Sorry for the code this is mij first time for many years I am posting here. The errorcode is Gtk-WARNING **: 16:42:43.042: Negative content width -32 (allocation 2, extents 17x17) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)

and: Gtk-WARNING **: 16:42:43.042: Negative content height -9 (allocation 1, extents 5x5) while allocating gadget (node button, owner GtkButton)

But I hope that someone can translate this wxpython code into code for Tkinter because I am reading books about Tkinter now

Comment: Code style is a bit problematic. Can you try fixing it by using the correct markdown?

Comment: You don't say what the error/warning is. Gtk is notorious for spewing messages across the screen, without actually causing a problem or stopping the program from running. What exactly is your problem?